# TypeError: moment().tz is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, momentjs

When testing using jasmine, I am getting this error.

> TypeError: moment().tz is not a function

My code that I try to test is:

```
let myDate = moment().tz(undefined, vm.timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

### Fix

If you're using Node.js, you may accidentally be using

`const moment = require('moment');` //**moment**

instead of

`const moment = require('moment-timezone');` //**moment-timezone**

Also, make sure you have installed moment-timezone with

`npm install moment-timezone --save`

### Explanation

The bug of requiring moment without timezones could occur by installing moment with `require('moment')`, later deciding to `npm install moment-timezone`, and then forgetting to update the `require`.

Comment: Any ideas why this is working on my local machine using moment (for years) and today it's throwing the error today? Using just 'moment' is also working locally on my machine but not working on colleagues machine. For example, this is works:

const moment = require('moment');
var date = moment(new Date()).tz('America/New_York').format('ddd. MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a');
(this works for me)

Comment: I don't fully understand your first question. Could you please reword? You can replace `moment(new Date())` with just `moment()`. I edited my response with the npm install commands, so please try them again on any environmen (your local machine, colleague's machine, production machines).

Comment: Just broke on my machine too. Just wondered why it didn't before.

Comment: @MattKim I have the same issue. When I run `npm i`, it installs my `moment@2.24.0`. I don't knw why but npm is installing `moment-timezone` with a sub repository `node_modules` and `moment@2.24.0`, so the moment lib I use is not updated. In production, I don't have this sub node_module dir with the wrong moment. Why is `npm` doing this on my computer everytime? I use same npm version on both machines.

Comment: @MattKim Finally it was an issue with the `package-lock.json`, delete it / `npm i` and it fixes the issue :/

Comment: I just spent way too much time trying to fix the test suite. Thanks so much for this answer!

Answer (score 59):

Below code for me...

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that you needed to install moment-timezone.

Comment: this worked, for almost two years, now i had to `import moment from 'moment-timezone'`

Comment: All I needed was ```import moment from "moment-timezone";```

Comment: this is the perfect and the simplest solution worked like a charm! TY

Comment: I am using react in my UI project, and got the same error, got resolved with these both imports.

Answer (score 10):

for Typescript: Works as of April 2021

```
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

cont x = moment.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ');

cont y = moment().isBetween(
            moment.tz('1-1-2021', 'America/Los_Angeles'),
            moment.tz('1-1-2021', 'America/Los_Angeles').add(2, 'hours'),
```

Comment: ```import 'moment-timezone';``` absolutely did it. thanks heaps!

Comment: I second that import. Just what I needed!! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Error ->** TypeError: (0 , moment_timezone_1.default) is not a function

This is typescript error,
by default It's take moment as function

I fix this issue, by replacing

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'
```

with

```
import * as moment from 'moment-timezone'
```

so

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

For Node.js, According to the original documentation:
[moment js documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/node-js/)

You should do

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

Then use it like this

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format();
```

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered this problem too. It works for years, but after a refactor, it doesn't work. As I've investigated, `moment-timezone@0.5.13` depends on `moment@>=2.9.0`, which might be different from `moment` itself.

In my case, `moment-timezone` uses `moment@2.24.0`, and `moment` itself version is `2.18.1`. Causes `moment-timezone` decorated *wrong* version of `moment`.

I've change yarn.lock like this:

```
moment-timezone@0.5.13:
  version "0.5.13"
  resolved "https://arti-dev.ss.aws.fwmrm.net/api/npm/fw-npm/moment-timezone/-/moment-timezone-0.5.13.tgz#99ce5c7d827262eb0f1f702044177f60745d7b90"
  integrity sha1-mc5cfYJyYusPH3AgRBd/YHRde5A=
  dependencies:
    moment ">= 2.9.0"

moment@2.18.1, moment@>= 2.9.0:
  version "2.18.1"
  resolved "https://arti-dev.ss.aws.fwmrm.net/api/npm/fw-npm/moment/-/moment-2.18.1.tgz#c36193dd3ce1c2eed2adb7c802dbbc77a81b1c0f"
  integrity sha1-w2GT3Tzhwu7SrbfIAtu8d6gbHA8=
```

`moment` & `moment-timezone` could be used substitute for each other in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use: moment-timezone

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const time = moment.tz(1412144245453, 'America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YYYY h:mm a');
console.log("time : ", time);
```

Output: time :  09/30/2014 11:17 pm

Answer (score 2):

Very old thread, but since I also ran into this issue and just as others have pointed out it was working and then stopped working, I tried digging into why it was happening like this?

So I had the following require statement in `foo.js`

```
const moment = require('moment');
moment.tz.setDefault('Europe/Berlin');
```

I ran my project and it worked totally fine, however one of my test files `bar.test.js` required something from `foo.js` and when I ran `mocha bar.test.js` I was presented with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDefault' of undefined`

The reason it worked in `foo.js` was because somewhere in my project I had done the following

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
```

and `moment-timezone` has a dependency on `moment`. So it loads the moment object first and then adds the additional timezone functionality as sort of a plugin. Then, when I require moment in my `foo.js` file it picks the object from the cache which has the `tz` functionality in it. But when I run my test file only, this `tz` functionality is not added on the moment object and hence it fails

So it is necessary to have `require('moment-timezone')` instead of `require('moment')`

I hope this helps

Answer (score -3):

Moment should be a function call. So use `let myDate = moment().tz(...)`

See https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/ for more details.

*EDIT*

You should also ensure that you are including the timezone extension to the moment library either through the correct npm install and require (for Node) or the correct script tags (for general browser usage). See the linked documents for the libraries/scripts to include.

*SECOND EDIT*

Should anyone have scrolled this far on a question with a +120 accepted answer:

The suggestion that `moment` was a function and requires brackets refers to the un-edited version of the posted question which had the syntax

`let myDate = moment.tz(undefined, vm.timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: fails with - moment(...).tz is not a function