# In vue.js moment.format() returning incorrect hours

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

The below code in returning 5 hours ago, when i just create a record

```
 formatDate(date) {
            return moment(date).fromNow();
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar issue, but in my case, it was -3 because of my time zone.

If your trying to parse a DB datetime, try with below code, it worked for me

```
formatDate(date) {
   return moment.utc(date)
}
```

It should return the datetime as it is in your DB

You can also return a formatted datetime

```
formatDate(date) {
   return moment.utc(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with [default timezone setting](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/default-timezone/) which may have been set to an undesired value in a different module or your app.

If you are on Node.js or in a browser, overwrite the default timezone by specifying it directly in the moment call: `moment(date).tz("America/Los_Angeles").fromNow();` Make sure that you are using `moment-timezone` library (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724909/14967413)).

If you are on Node.js, you can try setting default timezone of Node.js (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8083410/14967413)).